# How to solve recurrence relation T(n)=T(n^1/2)+n

Tags: recursion

T(n)=T(n^1/4)+n^1/2+n
     T(n^1/8)+n^1/4+n^1/2+n
     .
     .

```
 T(n^1/2^k)+n^1/k-1+n^1/k-2......+n
 I got k= loglog(n) but i am not able to solve the series by putting this k value into above series.
```

Answer (score 0):

Substituting n = 2^m first gives us

> T(2^m) = T(2^(m-1)) + 2^m

Now let S(m) = T(2^m). This vastly simplifies the recurrence relation to

> S(m) = S(m/2) + 2^m

By the master theorem,

> S(m) = O(2^m)

Finally,

> T(n) = T(2^m) = S(m) = O(2^m) = O(2^(log_2 n)) = O(n).